# How to get graph view in android?

Tags: android, plugins, graph, jar

I am developing an app where i need to represent some set of values in linear graph view. I don't have any idea how to display set of values in graphical view in android. Are there any  plugins to create these graph view.

Can anyone suggest me where to start to display some set of values in graphical view in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had some success generating line graphs with multiple lines in realtime with [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home).

Comment: here by default on x-axis & y-axis getting labels as "domain & range". how to remove those default labels and how is it possible to write my customized labels there.....?

Comment: There are functions on the XYPlot object called setDomainLabel and setRangeLabel.  The javadocs can be found (http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.5.0/)

Answer (score 3):

[GraphView](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html) might be of use to you.

Comment: +1 I struggled with the same problem a while ago and tried different free libraries. I found that GraphView was the easiest to use and gives really nice results quickly

Comment: @Kerry thanks for the answer but while i tried to execute the following solution which is downloaded from github, main page is loading and when i click on simple graphs or others graphs means it's getting error and in console it is showing error as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView$GraphViewSeries". can you help me with this..

Comment: code_finder: I'm afraid I've never used GraphView but only put it on my bookmarks list as I will need a graph eventually for something I am doing so right now I'm afraid I can't help other than search the source code for the missing Class.